# Clarification about using firebase and react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, backend

So lately I'm working on a ***react js*** project, before I start everything I searched and found that best way to use ***firebase*** with ***react*** is through express, everything was fine untill someone told me that I'm using it wrong, he explained that there's a `firebase auth` (which I'm using ) and `firebase admin sdk`, the first one must be used on the client side and the second one must be used on server side.

Basically I'm using `Axios` to send data to `express` and then run my `firebase Authentication` and then responding to my client side, is it wrong? Here's an example of checking if the user is logged in :

***Server.js***

```
const firebaseDb=require("firebase/database");
const firebaseAuth=require("firebase/auth");
const path = require('path');
const express= require("express");
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app=express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

const db=firebaseDb.getDatabase();
const auth=firebaseAuth.getAuth();
app.get('/checkAuth',(req, res)=>{  

const user=auth.currentUser;
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.      
    return res.status(200).send("auth ok");

  } else {
    // User is signed out
    return res.status(404).send("auth error");
  }

});
```

Does this work ? Or should I implement firebase on the client side directly? Or should I use firebase admin sdk here on my server?
Does using firebase on my client side makes my app vulnerable??
I appreciate any help I felt lost even after hours reading documentations.

Answer (score 1):

The flow I use when integrating firebase auth in my project is as follows

- I do the authentication on the front end side and pass auth token provided by Firebase SDK to the server in the Authorization header
- On the server-side, I use Firebase Admin SDK to verify the token

  ```
   const admin = require("firebase-admin");
   const serviceAccount = require('firebaseadmincredential.json'));
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });
  function firebaseTokenVerification(req, res, next) {

  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];

  admin
    .auth()
    .verifyIdToken(token)
    .then((response) => {
      // The token provided in the header is valid, if its reach the then block
      next(); 
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      // The token is invalid.
      return res
        .status(403)
        .send(
          'Invalid token'
        ); 

    });    }
  ```

The above code is used as an express middleware to the firebase token provided by the frontend, once authenticated then I am sure that the token provided by the frontend is valid and the request can be processed.

On the frontend I use the firebase/auth library and on the backend I use Firebase Admin SDK

Hope this answers your query.